# How to prove limit of $\frac{n\log n}{2^n}$ without using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

Using L'Hospital's rule, we can show that \begin{equation*}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n \log n}{2^n} = 0\end{equation*} But is it possible to do it using only basic techniques, without calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\leq\frac{n\log(n)}{2^n}\leq\frac{n^2}{2^n}$$

By the root test, the last term approaches $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and by the squeeze theorem, so does the middle term.

Comment: How do you show $\log n \leq n$ without calculus?

Comment: @Prasiortle, $e^{\log n}\lt e^n\iff n\lt e^n$.

Comment: That relies on the fact that $\log$ is strictly increasing, which is usually shown by considering its derivative.

Comment: Not necessarily. We were required to know that before taking any tasks, so no derivatives were mentioned then.

Comment: $\log n < n$, 
by $\textit{induction}$
$n = 1;\;\log 1 < 1$
suppose is true for $n$ let's prove for $n+1$

$\log (n + 1) =\log\left(n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \log n + \log(1 +\frac{1}{n}) <n + 1 $
as $1+\frac{1}{n} < e;\; \forall  n>1$

Comment: Thanks, that solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Binomial theorem we have :
$$2^n=(1+1)^n⩾1+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}=1+\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$
Therefore :
$$\frac{n\log n}{2^n}⩽\frac{n\log n}{1+\frac{n^2+n}{2}}=\frac{\log n}{n}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}},\ (2)$$
Now we will show that :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=0$$
We put $n=2^k$, we have :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\log 2^k}{2^k}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{k\log 2}{2^k}=0$$
Therefore we will have the result with inequality (2).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove by induction that $2^n >n^3>n$ for $n$ large enough.

Then
$$0\leq\frac{n\log(n)}{2^n}\leq\frac{n\log(2^n)}{2^n}\leq n^2\frac{\log(2)}{2^n} \leq \frac{2^n}{n} \frac{\log(2)}{2^n}$$